# Remove URL parameter using Twig in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a view with a result of a search and some buttons that add filters. The operation is very simple, by clicking on the button called again the current page passing a parameter `?foo=foo` by URL.

The system works well but I would like to click again on the filter button is active parameter referenced were eliminated.

Is this possible?

Twig code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 unfilled" style="float:none; margin-bottom:1.3em">
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'filter': 'pa'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('filter') == 'pa' ? 'active' : '' }}">Menor precio</a>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'filter': 'pd'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('filter') == 'pd' ? 'active' : '' }}">Mayor precio</a>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'stars1': '1'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('stars1') > 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">1 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></a>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'stars2': '3'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('stars2') > 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">2 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></a>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'stars3': '5'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('stars3') > 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">3 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></a>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'stars4': '7'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('stars4') > 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">4 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></a>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'stars5': '9'})) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm {{ app.request.get('stars5') > 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">5 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not entirely following, you want the `?foo=foo` to be removed from the link if it's already present in the current URL?

Comment: What I want is that from the same button that filters the data shown, discriminated through the variable passed by GET, parameter sets and is eliminated, since otherwise there is a list shown unfiltered by default.

Is to be put and elime the filter by clicking the same button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter set to null to avoid the parameter :

```
    {{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'filter': 'pd', 'star1': null, [...]} }}"
```

Do this for all parameters to disable (**[...]**).